# SOAP api login request not logging in

Tags: vb.net, soap

I have in a button click the following code:

> Dim pass As String
>      Dim user As String
>      Dim token As String

```
    pass = "Admin"
    user = "Admin"
    token = "tLxnoREj7gugKMulPzB0PGx6IZX2U3tO"

    Dim ISLogin As New WpfBrowserApplication1.ServiceReference1.apiLoginRequest
    ISLogin.security_token = token
    ISLogin.password = pass
    ISLogin.username = user
```

I go and check the api users logged in and it doesn't show up in logged in

Comment: I see where you set the values for the apiLoginRequest but don't actually call the method that logs you in.  You most likely need to pass that apiLoginRequest instance in to some method that actually logs the user in.

Comment: Dim ISLogin As New WpfBrowserApplication1.ServiceReference1.loginRequest(user, pass, token) still does not log me in. This is my first time using VB.net so please excuse me :S